# How do I stop updating all object's dictionaries in a list of objects? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

For a school project I am trying to convert a board game to a Python game

The game I am translating is 'stock ticker' and it involves buying and selling 6 'stocks'. The amount of players that can play is 2-8. The way I made a variable player count is creating a player class, and initializing a player object and adding it to a list at the start of the game.

```
class player:
    money = 5000
    stocks = {'Gold': 0, 'Tech': 0, 'Oil': 0, 'Grain': 0, 'Industry': 0, 'Bonds': 0}
```

I create the list with

```
for i in range(0, playersTotal):
     newPlayer = player()
     playerList.append(newPlayer)
```

The problem is that when players buy and sell stocks and the values are adjusted say with: (assuming player0 has 0 gold)

```
playerList[0].stocks['Gold'] += 1000
```

every dictionary of every player is updated the same way

```
print(playerList[1].stocks['Gold'])
>>>1000
```

I don't know why the dictionary is updated for all the player objects in the list because when the money attribute is adjusted it stays separate: (if both players have 0 money)

```
playerList[0].money += 1000
print(playerList[1].money)
>>> 0
```

How do I keep the dictionaries separate?

Comment: You are using the *same dictionary* across instances. When you mutate the dictionary, the effects will be seen across instances.

Comment: You need to define the variables within the `__init__` function.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer while that is good advice, fundamentally the variables need to be instance variables, wherever they are defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because your `stocks` is `static`, you should have it as an `instance` variable and not as `static` variable, try this instead:

```
class player:    
    def __init__(self):
        self.money = 5000
        self.stocks = {'Gold': 0, 'Tech': 0, 'Oil': 0, 'Grain': 0, 'Industry': 0, 'Bonds': 0}
```

Since your `stocks` variable is `static`, all the instances use the same `stocks`, so when you update its value from any instance, it'll get updated for all the instances, since the variable is shared for all the instances.

**OUTPUT**

```
>>> for i in range(0, 10):
...      newPlayer = player()
...      playerList.append(newPlayer)
... 
>>> playerList[0].stocks['Gold'] += 5000
>>> playerList[0].stocks['Gold'] 
5000
>>> playerList[1].stocks['Gold']
0
```